# Any idea why Android Kotlin SharedPreferences is crashing my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I try to save a key-value pair persistently by use of shared preferences in Android Kotlin.
When putting the object initialisation into my mainActivity-Class and run it in debug mode on my phone the app immediately crashes with no debug information.

Phone: Samsung SM-A146P
OS: Android 15 / UI Core 5.1

The following code is causing the crash:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.xpz.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 ... }
```

I have no clue why it is not working. Do I need to set some permission?

Comment: Can you also share your logcat error ? Every crash has an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you initialize SharedPreferences in the MainActivity, before the Activity has been fully constructed. you should place it in the onCreate

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.xpz.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    }
}
```

Comment: That's it - sometimes there are too much trees to see the forest.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating shared preferences on Application class creation. This class is good to initialise all global classes and libraries if needed. Also, if you are using dependency injection you can create these classes with SingletonComponent. Helps to organise code and prevents you from creating multiple instances that could cause issues along the line.